# React Hooks won't work on Firebase Cloud Functions Error: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, react-hooks, next.js

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to host my SSR Nextjs app. I can deploy the Nextjs app on firebase cloud functions and access it with clean URLs without React Hooks but with React Hooks I get an error message:

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

[This issue has also been reported here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/601) on a GitHub firebase/firebase-functions repo.

There is also a [reproducible example repo](https://github.com/maotora/nextjs-firebase-example) to test the bug (useState hook implemented in [pages/about.tsx](https://github.com/maotora/nextjs-firebase-example/blob/master/src/app/pages/about.tsx) file).

This is done on, React: 16.10.2

Comment: I'm currently working on Next.js app which uses Hooks and needs to be deployed to Firebase, so I'll keep you updated if I could achieve this with no errors :)

Comment: @RomanBatsenko, this [firebase gcp nextjs setup](https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-gcp-examples/tree/master/functions-nextjs) worked for me  
I didn't post the answer because I haven't invested time in figuring out what really made the bug in that other setup. I thought It'd be babel's presence in the gcp example and that was it.
If you come up with a working explanation, please update us with an answer!

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Ok, I'll write here if I figure out what's going on

Answer (score 1):

The problem superficially stems from two copies of the react source code. I'm not 100% sure how it works so I won't even try to explain the root cause of the problem.

To fix the problem, please place the app inside the functions folder and remove package.json. Unfortunately, all the dependencies of app must necessarily be dependencies of functions. Then, change `next.config.js` to this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = { distDir: './next' };
```

and `index.js` to this:

```
const dir = __dirname + "/app" const app = next({ dev, dir, conf: {distDir: 'next'} })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, actually I'm not really supporting the idea of coupling app into functions directory but I will look into this solution you presented :-)

Comment: Just fyi, the author replied and said he has a new example repo [here](https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-gcp-examples/tree/master/functions-nextjs). To your point, it seems fundamentally impossible to separate the two unless you dig in to the react code, because you need the same react source and node_modules folder. The author's example has the same problem. I don't know if it offers any other advantages. If anything, it further entangles firebase and app so I wouldn't use it.